# How to get current screen orientation in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, mobile-safari

I am trying to get the current screen orientation of iOS however my function which work on chrome dev tool emulator and desktop but it doesn't work on iOS.

Here is my function:

```js
export type ScreenOrientation = "landscape" | "portrait";

export function getScreenOrientation(): ScreenOrientation
{
  if (window.screen.availHeight > window.screen.availWidth)
    return "portrait";
  else
    return "landscape";
}
```

and here is how my program rougthly do to detect the screen orientation change and to use the function:

```js
  import { getScreenOrientation } from "../../Utils/getOrientation";
  const shoWPortraitModeError = getScreenOrientation() == "landscape" ? false : true;
  window.onorientationchange = function () {
    const newState = getScreenOrientation() == "landscape" ? false : true;
    console.log("window.onorientationchange: ", newState)
    shoWPortraitModeError  = newState;
  };
```

I tried using `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width` however it didn't worked. Here is the function:

```js
export type ScreenOrientation = "landscape" | "portrait";

export function getScreenOrientation(): ScreenOrientation
{
  if (window.screen.availHeight > window.screen.availWidth)
    return "portrait";
  else
    return "landscape";
}
```

I launch the iOS safari debugger on a mac vm and I noticed that the `window.screen` value doesn't changes when I turn the screen:
[image: thing i noticed]

It made me wonder what are the different property I can use to detect the screen orientation on ios ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging around in the intelisense of the dev console of the safari debugger, I found that you can use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` properties to detect the screen orienation.

Here is how you can use the function:

```js
export type ScreenOrientation = "landscape" | "portrait";

export function getScreenOrientation(): ScreenOrientation
{
  if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
    return "portrait";
  else
    return "landscape";
}
```

Comment: Clean and good. You do have to take into account that a user can switch between screen orientation after this function has run.

Comment: What about when keyboard is open?

Comment: It's the same logic, the screen width will always be bigger when its horizontal

Comment: innerHeight will not always be greater than innerWidth when screen is vertical and keyboard is open.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do some CSS, you can use media queries.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation

Basically you can use `@media (orientation: landscape) {}`

If you want it in JS, for other purposes, you can use:

```
let orientation = (screen.orientation || {}).type || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;

if (orientation === "landscape-primary") {
  console.log("That looks good.");
} else if (orientation === "landscape-secondary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... the screen is upside down!");
} else if (orientation === "portrait-secondary" || orientation === "portrait-primary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... you should rotate your device to landscape");
} else if (orientation === undefined) {
  console.log("The orientation API isn't supported in this browser :(");
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the css version of your solution as the js version didn't worked in safari

Answer (score 2):

Despite being deprecated, this works on iOS 16 Safari (late 2022):

```js
// rotate right
window.orientation // -90

// rotate left
window.orientation // 90
```

Comment: Speaking of deprecated. What good is an easy new way to get screen orientation when it is NOT supported by all currently used browsers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation - is Safari the new IE? And if so, why isn't anybody saying anything?

Comment: My iOS (15.7) does not support "screen.orientation", and "window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth" does not distinguish between rotating device left and rotating device right.   So using window.orientation is only way that works as OP requested.

Comment: @Josh In my iOS rotating right and left gives values of -90 and +90 respectively.  So you might want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently (early 2023) using this little line that returns the angle of the orientation which I can interpret myself:

`let orientation = (screen.orientation.angle || window.orientation);`

A value other than 0 means it is not portrait, and 90 means reverse portrait.

Comment: Thanks -- given this, how would you detect _changes_ in orientation though? Is there an event that is triggered even on older iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.matchMedia

```
   const landscapeQuery = window.matchMedia('(orientation: landscape)');

   function handleOrientationChange(mediaQuery) {
     if (mediaQuery.matches) {
       console.log('Device is in landscape mode');
     } else {
       console.log('Device is in portrait mode');
     }
   }

   landscapeQuery.addEventListener("change", handleOrientationChange);
```